# job status in SLURM

Tags: linux, batch-processing, hpc, slurm

I would like to view all my recent jobs run on the cluster (completed, failed, and running). I would also like to see 1 entry per job.  Executing `sacct` retruns 3 lines per job with `State: FAILED, FAILED, COMPLETED`. What does this mean and how do I view the actual information I would like to see?

I don't understand what a `JobName` of `true` means either.

Here is a copy of the output:

```
   JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode 
 ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- 
 2160852               R   interact cluster_u+          2  COMPLETED      0:0 
 2160864               R   interact cluster_u+          2  COMPLETED      0:0 
 2161424               R   interact cluster_u+          2  COMPLETED      0:0 
 2161430               R   interact cluster_u+          0 CANCELLED+      0:0 
 2161431               R   interact cluster_u+          2  COMPLETED      0:0 
 2161668               R   interact cluster_u+          2  COMPLETED      0:9 
 2161682          myjob+    general cluster_u+          2     FAILED      1:0 
 2161682.bat+      batch            cluster_u+          1     FAILED      1:0 
 2161682.0          true            cluster_u+          1  COMPLETED      0:0 
 2161683          myjob+    general cluster_u+          2     FAILED      1:0 
 2161683.bat+      batch            cluster_u+          1     FAILED      1:0 
 2161683.0          true            cluster_u+          1  COMPLETED      0:0
```

Submission script (note that values in <% %> are processed by package BatchJobs in R):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #SBATCH -J <%= job.name %>            # name of the job
 #SBATCH -p general
 #SBATCH --mem <%= resources$memory %>    # Memory requirements in Kbytes
 #SBATCH -o ./logs/<%= job.name %>_log.txt    # Memory requirements in Kbytes


 eval "R --vanilla --slave < <%= rscript %>"
```

Answer (score 3):

sacct will print one line per job followed with one line per job step in that job.

```
 2161683          myjob+    general cluster_u+          2     FAILED      1:0  <- the job
 2161683.bat+      batch            cluster_u+          1     FAILED      1:0  <- the batch script
 2161683.0          true            cluster_u+          1  COMPLETED      0:0  <- the R step
```

The job has status failed because the script itself has status failed. You have one job step in your script, and it terminated correctly.

I often resort to  `sacct |grep -v "^[0-9]*\."` to get job information only.

Comment: also, what is a "job step"?

Comment: Broadly speaking, if your job consists of several commands, each one is a job step.

Comment: Why do you use eval rather than just running the command line ? If that really is the last line of your script, I'am confused as to why your job fails while your job step does not.

Comment: yes that is the entire submission script; the `eval` is a relic from a while ago that i should really change

Comment: Side note: you request 2 cpus.. Is your R script multithreaded ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. The script only generates two lines per job in sacct and their status depends whether the R script was correct or not. But I see no XXXXXX.0 line. I guess you would need to have a look at the Slurm logs to find more information..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39098/discussion-between-nnwizard-and-alex)